# Upgrading from Jquery 1.4.2 to 1.5.2 breaks my site

Tags: jquery, wordpress, upgrade

I have a wordpress site that was built for me by a developer some time ago, which I am slowly working on finishing on my local machine. I am a designer but I can work my way around CSS/JS/PHP somewhat blindly. Copy and paste sort of stuff...

I am trying to upgrade the jquery file it uses from 1.4.2 to 1.5.2, for a range of reasons, but I am finding that if I try to the jquery stops working all together. I am not sure where to even start troubleshooting this. I would be greatful for any assistance that anyone can offer in helping me troubleshoot this.

The site uses a mix os scripts, including jquery ui, masonry, and lazy loading. All quite standard stuff. It does also have a custom written script for some of the interface face effects.

I can provide samples of code, but not really sure where to start.

Comment: Do you get any Javascript errors? they could help find the problem. (Firefox Web Developer Toolbar should give you this info)

Comment: Sorry I can't provide a link as it's all running locally on my Mac with MAMP. I have just installed the web dev toolbar you mentioned. What do I do from here to check the javascript errors?

Comment: There is a small little bug icon on the bottom right. By default, it is grey; i.e. turned off so right-click and "Enable All Panels". If there is a JavaScript error, it should appear on the Console tab.

Comment: Ok I did it and I get 3 things come up. I can't past the error code here though, it's saying I have a maximum word limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding double quotes around the attribute value ("/category/projects")?

```
$('a[href*="/category/projects"]').bind('click', function(e) {
```

Comment: Well I'll be. That's fixed it. That's all it was. You are Yoda incarnate. It's all working fine now with version 1.5.2. Thank you for the prompt and helpful assistance to all the people who responded.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no coding knowledge of any real essence I would call your developer again.

It would seem your js relies on deprecated material and upgrading causes them to not work anymore.

You could create more damage than good.

Comment: What is the site address I'll take a peek?

Comment: Would love to give it to you but it's all on my local machine :(

Answer (score 0):

Because we can't see the source code, enable the developer tools in Safari - Preferences>>>Advanced>>Show Develop Menu in menu Bar - or use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox or as standalone and use the error console to find what JS is loading, what's conflicting and the errors.